# Can you generate only a subset of mipmaps for an MTLTexture using a texture view?

Tags: objective-c, macos, metal, metalkit

I'm trying to generate only a subset of mipmaps for a texture by using a texture view but all of my attempts result in Metal throwing the following error:

> Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Ignored (for causing prior/excessive GPU errors) (IOAF code 4)

**Pseudo Code:**

```
// This is a texture that is 1024 x 1024 with 11 mipmap levels.
id<MTLTexture> destinationTexture = ...

// Extract all mipmap levels from 256 and smaller
NSRange levelsRange = NSMakeRange(2, 9);

// Create a new texture view for that includes only those levels from the destination texture.
id<MTLTexture> destinationView = [destinationTexture newTextureViewWithPixelFormat:destinationTexture.pixelFormat
                                                                       textureType:destinationTexture.textureType
                                                                            levels:levelsRange
                                                                            slices:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];

// Copy a region from a source texture into the destination view, 
// starting at level 0 of the view which, I think, should represent
// level 2 of its parent texture.
[blitEncoder copyFromTexture:sourceTexture
                 sourceSlice:0
                 sourceLevel:0
                sourceOrigin:sourceOrigin
                  sourceSize:sourceSize
                   toTexture:destinationView
            destinationSlice:0
            destinationLevel:0
           destinationOrigin:destinationOrigin];

// Generate mipmaps on the destination view. This causes the crash. 
[blitEncoder generateMipmapsForTexture:destinationView];
```

My intent here is to quickly render some lower-resolution content and copy that to the texture, then progressively render the higher resolution content. I could render the content for each mipmap level explicitly, but I was hoping to just pick a few "cutoff" levels and then have Metal generate the mipmaps for all levels below the cutoff.

As it stands, the blit correctly executes and the texture is updated, but it crashes if I try and generate the mipmaps. If I don't generate the mipmaps, then I'll need to explicitly sample from that level using `lod()`, whereas I was hoping to use the `bias()` feature instead to restrict the range.

The stack trace is:

[image: Stack Trace]

Comment: The stack trace suggests you're working with the drawable's texture and maybe that you've kept a strong reference to a previous drawable's texture by accident. Does it work if you work with a texture of your own creation?

Comment: None of my code, that I can tell, grabs a reference to the view's current drawable until I've called `[commandBuffer presentDrawable:view.currentDrawable]; [commandBuffer commit]` which are the last two calls in my `drawInMTKView:`. If I replace `destinationView` with `destinationTexture` and an appropriate value for `destinationLevel`, then it does work but, not surprisingly, the mipmap generator will overwrite the contents of the lower levels with whatever was in level 0, which might still be empty.

Comment: As an aside, though it doesn't appear to make a difference, but am I allowed to make sequential calls to `[blitEncoder copyFromTexture...]` with a different sourceTexture but the same destinationTexture? I'm using a single `commandBuffer` a single `blitEncoder` and making repeated calls to copy sourceTexture tiles into a destinationTexture, which might be larger than the sourceTile size. The mipmap generation occurs after all the `copyFromTexture:` calls. This all appears to work when I use full textures, but not with texture views.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why such sequential blit commands would be a problem. On thinking about it some more, I think the stack trace suggests something else. I think something in Metal took a lock, encountered an error, and didn't free the lock in the error path out of the code. Later, that same thread entered the code path shown, where it tried to lock that same lock. Since those locks are not recursive, that's not valid, is detected, and aborts.